# Having Trouble Using Orange Data Mining in Linear Progression in Continuous Data

Tags: orange

I'm having trouble with a simple task. I just imported an Excel sheet (CSV) into Orange.

It recognized the features as continuous, but it couldn't run Linear Progression or Discretized on it.

How can I debug/fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Orange needs either a one-line or three-line header. Yours is two-line, hence it will cause confusion. Either add an extra blank line below the second or remove the second line altogether (Orange should recognize these values correctly).